# Sorting by first two letters in first column then by text in second column

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my job, every day I receive excel file with 2 columns (A1, B2) of unsorted data.
For example:

```
A1 B2
DD E
AA Y
CC C
AA W
CC B
CE I
AA P
CE C
DD Y
```

What I wanted to do is to sort it first by 2 letters of cell in first column and then by text in second column. Like this:

```
A1 B2
AA P
AA W
AA Y
CC B
CC C
CE C
CE I
DD E
DD Y
```

As you can see, text in B2 is sorted from A to Z, but within groups from A1 (AA, CC, CE, DD)

To be honest, I'm not very familiar with Excel. This kind of multiconditional sorting I need to create in some macro, vba?

I tried to use multisort option (sort by Column A, Sort on Values, order A to Z, then sort by Column B, Sort on Values, order A to Z) but it's not working how I wanted.
Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: Add a level to your sort (top left button in the sort window)

Comment: "I tried to use multisort option (sort by Column A, Sort on Values, order A to Z, then sort by Column B, Sort on Values, order A to Z) but it's not working how I wanted." How is it working? This will do what you are asking to do.

Comment: Sorry, but after using that, it just sort all cells in B2, but destroy sorting in A1. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: You clearly are doing two sorts instead of *adding a level* to a single sort

Comment: Alright, I know what was wrong with this. I need to clarify one thing.
In the example I made: Cells in A1 contain only 2 letters, but in reality, they have 2 letters and 6 random numbers: Like this: LX135456 and every one number is different. That's why it wasn't working.
I'm really sorry about that :(
I will edit my topic a little

Comment: If you want a sort to only take the first two characters in some cells into account, the easiest thing may be to have a helper column with said two letters

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I tried something like that. I moved cells in B column to C column, then in B column I used Left Function. After that I used multisort options for A, B, C and moved back cells in C column to B column.

One more time, big thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

in column C use the following formula `=left(A1,2)&B1` or whatever appropriate cell reference, then sort only by column C