# Sort column by first two letters

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I would like to sort a column but only based on the two first letters. When the two first letters are the same, I would like to sort on another column.

This [stackoverflow answer](https://superuser.com/a/1525556/1658751) mentions this solution:

> in column C use the following formula =left(A1,2)&B1 or whatever
> appropriate cell reference, then sort only by column C

Is there a more optimised way of doing it? Creating a column to sort on it and then deleting it sounds bad practice.

Comment: Does the first column contain values with more than 2 characters?

Comment: Select the table, Data tab -> Sort. Sort by the first column (ascending order). add the second column, then sort it.

Comment: Yes the first column contains values with more than 2 characters.

Comment: What you're suggesting unfortunately doesn't work because it will sort the first column on more than only the two first characters :/

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMvfQ.png)?

Comment: Yes, without sorting on a third `=left(A1,2)&B1` column because it sounds not optimised (i have to do it automatically for thousands of .xlsm files) if possible :)

Comment: With Power query, you will have to create a 3rd column, but it can be removed when the sorting is complete. Caveat: Another table will be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have access to dynamic arrays by virtue of being an O365 Excel user, you are correct.  You can optimize this and not create a helper column.

The SORTBY function allows you to sort a range or array based on the sort order of other columns, *or based on the sort order of another array, that may be a dynamic array stored in memory.*  So we'll create a dynamic array that is the left two characters of every cell in column A, and use *that* array as our primary sort key, and column B as our secondary sort key.

Let's assume I have 5 columns.  The primary index is in column A, the secondary  index is in column B, and other content that I want to sort by A and B is located in columns C, D and E.

Thus:

`=SORTBY( A1:E10, LEFT(A1:A10,2), 1, B1:B10, 1 )`

will create a spilled array that is the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it works, I cannot write this in A1, so I have to write this in F1 and delete columns A to E? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I get the "There is a circular formula" when I do this. Maybe I can programmatically do this in VBA?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Agreed, this will not work to "replace" the data.  The very nature of Excel formulas is that a cell either contains a value (like "AAC") or it contains a formula that tells the cell where to go retrieve data and then formulate its result. In Excel you generally have 3 choices when sorting:  (a) You can put the formula somewhere else, so your original remains and you create a second, sorted/filter set to work with.  (b) you can select it and use the menu options manually.  Thie requires creating a helper column. Or (c) you can script it, such as VBA.

Comment: I ended up scripting the creation of a new column, then sorting with your formula and then deleting the column automatically. I reckon actually scripting the sorting is gonna be a disaster compared to the optimised functions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your table, go to Data -> Get data -> From Other Sources -> From Table/Range.
2. Select the first column (the one you want to sort by the first 2 characters). Right click on it, select Duplicate Column.
3. Select the duplicated column. Click Transform tab -> Extract -> First characters. Set to count to 2. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>. The duplicated column will now only display the first 2 characters.
4. Sort the the duplicated column in ascending order. Then, sort the second column in ascending order.

[image]

5. Remove the duplicated column. Close Power query Editor. Click on <kbd>Keep</kbd> to save the changes.
6. A new table will be created with the first column sorted ascendingly based on the first two characters and sorted in ascending order on the second column.

[image]